# Python split by character only if wrapped in parenthesis

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing a large text file that has key value pairs separated by '='. I need to split these key value pairs into a dictionary. I was simply going to split by '='. However I noticed that some of the values contain the equals sign character. When a value contains the equals sign character, it seems to be always wrapped in parenthesis.

Question: How can I split by equals sign only when the equals sign is not in between two parenthesis?

Example data:

```
PowSup=PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)
```

Desired output:

```
{'PowSup': 'PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)'}
```

UPDATE: The data does not seem to have any nested parenthesis. (Hopefully that remains true in the future)

UPDATE 2: The key doesn't ever seem to have equals sign either.

UPDATE 3: The full requirements are much more complicated and at this point I am stuck so I have opened up a new question here: [Python parse output of mixed format text file to key value pair dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104242/python-parse-output-of-mixed-format-text-file-to-key-value-pair-dictionaries)

Comment: Does the key ever have an `=` in it?  Or only the value?

Comment: Are there always parenthesis? Can they appear also in key string? Bigger sample of input data could help.

Comment: What is the deliminator between different key-value pairs? Is it a new line? There has to be one, doesn't it? How do you tell when one value ends and the next key starts?

Answer (score 3):

You could try partition('=') to split from the first instance

```
'PowSup=PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)'.partition('=')[0:3:2]
```

Comment: this will return `('PowSup', '=', 'PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)')`

Comment: Now it should be ok I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
mydict=dict()
for line in file:
    k,v=line.split('=',1)
    mydict[k]=v
```

Comment: This works only if there is one expression per line.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `str.index()` function:

```
s = "PowSup=PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)"
pos = s.index('=')   # detecting the first position of `=` character
print {s[:pos]:s[pos+1:]}
```

The output:

```
{'PowSup': 'PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) operation to a single split (the first `=`):

```
>>> x = "PowSup=PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)"
>>> x.split('=', 1)
['PowSup', 'PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)']
```

You can then use these values to populate your dict:

```
>>> x = "PowSup=PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)"
>>> key, value = x.split('=', 1)
>>> out = {}
>>> out[key] = value
>>> out
{'PowSup': 'PS1(type=Emerson,fw=v.03.05.00)'}
```